# Dymanically creating a div using jquery causes syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have to create view application form after submission of a form by using Bootstrap. I created it by using two 'div'. How can I dynamically create a div on button click?

```
<i> Section I: Insured Information</h4>
<div class="form-group dynamicDiv">
    <!--Wrap labels and form controls needed for optimum spacing !-->
    <div class="row top-buffer">
        <label class="col-md-5 labelAlignment">
        Name<span class="red">*</span></label>
        <div class="text-box-height col-md-7">
        <!-- Form controls automatically receive some global styling with              Bootstrap: !-->
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtInsuredName"   placeholder="Enter Name"
              required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter UserName')"      oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
        <!-- To insert plain text next to label within a horizontal form, .form-control-static class is used  !-->
        <div class="col-md-10 form-control-static lblInsuredName">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row top-buffer">
    <label class="col-md-5 labelAlignment">
        Mailing Address Line 1<span class="red">*</span></label>
    <div class="text-box-height col-md-7 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtInsuredAddress1" placeholder="Enter Address"
            required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter Mailing Address1')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
        <div class="col-md-10 form-control-static lblInsuredAddress1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
            <div class="row top-buffer"> </div>
            <div class="row top-buffer"> </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit">
                Submit</button>
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-info"  id="btnView">
                ViewData</button>
            <input runat="server" type="hidden" id="hdnKey" value=""  />
            <div class="row top-buffer"> </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
<i>
```

I have stored values i values in JSON format as .json file, and stored the values into a hidden field.
But I have to dynamically create the second div in every textbox field in the form.
And my jQuery function is:

```
/*****************Function for showing view page using Query String******************/


$("#btnView").click(function() {
    var strUrlView = new String(window.location.href);
    strUrlView = strUrlView + "?key=" + $("#hdnKey").val();
    window.location.href = strUrlView;
});
var strUrl = new String(window.location.href);
if (strUrl.indexOf("key") != -1) {
    /*****************Hiding form-control div's ******************/
    //to decrypt the uniqueID
    var strKey = strUrl.split("key=")[1].replace("#", '');
    //Reading json and get data from json file to create the view
    var strFile = 'Data/JsonData/' + strKey + '.json';
    $.getJSON(strFile, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(Key, Value) {
            //to convert control to span
            var ctrl = $("#" + Key);
            for (var k in Value) {
                //for replaceing textbox to label
                if (typeof Value[k] !== 'function') {
                    var strlblname = "div." + k.replace("txt", "lbl").replace("ddl", "lbl");
                    $(strlblname).text(Value[k]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
});
```

I tried to append like this:

```
for (var k in Value) {
    $(".dynamicDiv").append(" <div class="form-group dynamicDiv"></div>")
    //for replaceing textbox to label
    if (typeof Value[k] !== 'function') {
        var strlblname = "div." + k.replace("txt", "lbl").replace("ddl", "lbl");
        $(strlblname).text(Value[k]);
    }
}
```

but it shows syntax error. What is the mistake I have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function(Key, Value) {
            //to convert control to span
            var ctrl = $("#" + Key);
            for (var k in Value) {
                $('.viewDiv' + j++).text(Value[k]);
            }
});
```

I have removed the div with the 'form-static-control' and added the class 'viewDiv' in the div which has class 'text-box-height'.